# I don't see the Run as account in azure automation account

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-rbac

A colleague created a Run as account in an azure automation account. I don't see this `Run as account`  although i have owner rights on this automation account. I have given myself Owner rights on the subscription, after that i have started to see it. With Contributor rights on the subscription level, it is not seen as well.

I want to use least privilege permission principle. So what is the minimum permissions to see a Run as account in an azure automation account?

Answer (score 0):

If  we want to create `Run as account` in Azure automation account, we need to do some steps. Every step needs different permissions.

1. Create Azure AD Application. When we complete the step, we need Azure AD role [Application Developer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-developer)
2. Add a credential to the application. With this step, we need Azure AD role [Application Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-administrator)
3. Create and get an Azure AD service principal. Doing the step, we need Azure AD role Application Administrator
4. Assign or get the Azure role for the specified principal. We need have these Azure RABC permissions

   - Microsoft.Authorization/Operations/read
   - Microsoft.Authorization/permissions/read
   - Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/read
   - Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write
   - Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read
   - Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/delete
5. Create or remove an Automation certificate. Completing the step, we need to be Contributor on the resource group.

For more details, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-security-overview#permissions)

Comment: Sorry it doesn't answer my question

Comment: @MoonHorse If you can view page, we need to have permissions to create Run as account

Comment: yes, that's correct but the run as account is already created by someone else who has enough permissions. But i don't see it unless i have owner rights on subscription.